# googledriveのファイルをgoogle colaboratoryで扱いたい

Tags: python, python3, google-colaboratory

googledriveのファイルをgoogle colaboratoryで扱いたいのですがgoogledriveの使いたいファイルのidを入力すると以下のようなエラーが出ました

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google.appengine'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/googleapiclient/discovery_cache/file_cache.py", line 33, in <module>
    from oauth2client.contrib.locked_file import LockedFile
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'oauth2client.contrib.locked_file'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/googleapiclient/discovery_cache/file_cache.py", line 37, in <module>
    from oauth2client.locked_file import LockedFile
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'oauth2client.locked_file'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/googleapiclient/discovery_cache/__init__.py", line 41, in autodetect
    from . import file_cache
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/googleapiclient/discovery_cache/file_cache.py", line 41, in <module>
    'file_cache is unavailable when using oauth2client >= 4.0.0 or google-auth')
ImportError: file_cache is unavailable when using oauth2client >= 4.0.0 or google-auth
```

Comment: スタック・オーバーフローへようこそ！　コードを追記していただくことは可能ですか？

Answer (score 0):

google colaboratoryの画面上方のメニューより
「挿入」→「コードスニペット」　を押下
画面左側のスニペット一覧から
「Open files from Google Drive」

を選択すると、コードがセルにコピーされます。
そのセルを実行することで（要認証） Google Driveがマウントされますので、Google Driveのファイルを扱えるようになるかと思います。